# Trying to add values to an ArrayList in seperate class

Tags: java, android

I have a class titled `Globals` and I'm trying to add elements while using a different class, but I keep getting the  `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error. Here is my code:

```
ListIterator lit=listOfNames.
while(lit.hasNext())
{
       Globals.listOfNames.add(lit.next().toString());
       Log.e(TAG, lit.next()+" ");
 }
```

and I initialized it in the global class as:

```
public static ArrayList<String> ListOfStdntNames=new ArrayList<>();
```

**Why is the exception being thrown?** Thank you for the help.

Comment: which line is your error flagging?

Comment: You have `Globals.listOfNames` in your code, but the variable you show is `ListOfStdntNames`. Which is it?

Comment: You need getter method and then it should be like this `Globals.getListOfNames().add(lit.next().toString());`

Comment: @bakero98 what would that accomplish? The variable is public.

Comment: Can you please post the full code of the relevant classes along with the log?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `next()` function twice inside your loop. Once during add and once during Log.
Change it like this:

```
while(list.hasNext()) {
    String nextVal = list.next().toString();
    Globals.listOfNames.add(nextVal);
    Log.e(TAG, nextVal+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not define your arraylist as static.

you should do it like this:

add a method inside global class:

```
public void AddToArrayList(String yourValue){
    yourArrayList.add(yourValue);
}
```

then call that method from other class:

```
Global global = new Global();

while(list.hasNext()) {
     String nextVal = list.next().toString();
     global.AddToArrayList(nextVal);
}
```